# Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, flask

I'm building an admin for Flask and SQLAlchemy, and I want to pass the HTML for the different inputs to my view using `render_template`. The templating framework seems to escape the HTML automatically, so all `<"'>` characters are converted to HTML entities. How can I disable that so that the HTML renders correctly?

Answer (score 530, accepted):

To turn off autoescaping when rendering a value, use the `|safe` filter.

```
{{ something|safe }}
```

Only do this on data you trust, since rendering untrusted data without escaping is a cross-site scripting vulnerability.

Answer (score 151):

[MarkupSafe](https://markupsafe.palletsprojects.com) provides Jinja's autoescaping behavior. You can import `Markup` and use it to declare a value HTML safe from the code:

```
from markupsafe import Markup
value = Markup('<strong>The HTML String</strong>')
```

Pass that to the templates and you don't have to use the `|safe` filter on it.

Answer (score 50):

From the Jinja docs section [*HTML Escaping*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/):

> When automatic escaping is enabled everything is escaped by default
> except for values explicitly marked as safe. Those can either be
> marked by the application or in the template by using the `|safe`
> filter.

Example:

```html
<div class="info">
   {{ data.email_content|safe }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

When you have a lot of variables that don't need escaping, you can use an [`autoescape` override](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#autoescape-overrides) block:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ something }}
{{ something_else }}
<b>{{ something_important }}</b>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 5):

For handling line-breaks specifically, I tried a number of options before finally settling for this:

```
{% set list1 = data.split('\n') %}
{% for item in list1 %}
{{ item }}
  {% if not loop.last %}
  <br/>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it's compatible with the auto-escaping, leaving everything nice and safe.  It can also be combined with filters, like urlize.

Of course it's similar to Helge's answer, but doesn't need a macro (relying instead on Jinja's built-in `split` function) and also doesn't add an unnecesssary `<br/>` after the last item.

Answer (score 3):

Some people seem to turn **autoescape** off which carries **security risks** to manipulate the string display.

If you only want to insert some linebreaks into a string and convert the linebreaks into `<br />`, then you could take a **jinja macro** like:

```
{% macro linebreaks_for_string( the_string ) -%}
{% if the_string %}
{% for line in the_string.split('\n') %}
<br />
{{ line }}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
{{ the_string }}
{% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

and in your **template** just call this with

```
{{ linebreaks_for_string( my_string_in_a_variable ) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `safe` filter in your template, and then sanitize the HTML with [the `bleach` library](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in your view. Using bleach, you can whitelist the HTML tags that you need to use.

This is the safest, as far as I know. I tried both the `safe` filter and the `Markup` class, and both ways allowed me to execute unwanted JavaScript. Not very safe!