# How to return raw html in a Flask app bypassing template transformations

Tags: python, flask

I have just started building my first Flask app, which currently simply returns output of `inspect` for my objects inside table tags. The problem is that instead of the html I expect, a template engine messes layout up creating new tags (I guess it parses dict's curly brackets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question I don't really understand, why and where this `inspect` is ran, but it is possible to escape output like this:

```
{{ object | e }}
```

Or you can escape things inside template by using `'foo'` or `{% raw %}`:

```
{{ '{{' }}

{% raw %}
   {% %}
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The actual problem was in `<>` brackets around strings representing variables, and that Chrome has added extra closing tags in the inspect window, which led me to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Really helps when using Javascript templating library like jQuery.tmpl as the syntax is similar.

Comment: seams this doesn't work anymore and you need to do `{{ object|safe }}` https://stackoverflow.com/a/3206446/10917416