# Any way to add a new line from a string with the '\n' character in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I was playing around with flask when I came across an odd problem with the '\n' character. it dosen't seem to have an effect in my browser, I tried putting 
 in there but it didn't work, any ideas?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
test=Flask(__name__)
@test.route('/')
def root():
    str='yay\nsuper'
    return str
test.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Newlines only have an effect on HTML rendering in specific cases. You would need to use an HTML tag representing a newline, such as `<br/>`.

```
def root():
    str='yay<br/>super'
    return str
```

Comment: This is correct, but if you wouldn't mind, if I was putting this into a block element how would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a block element?

Comment: for example, if I were to put a variable like this

         {% block content %}
{{stuffs}}

         {% endblock %}

Comment: Where do you need to put the `<br/>`, you're asking? It would go wherever you'd usually put the newline.

Comment: Oddly, it just prints out the actual <br/> I'm asking if there is a way to fix this

Maybe I wasn't clear it would be something like `return render_template('index.html',stuffs=list')`
and in the HTML `{%block content%}
 {{stuffs}}
{%endblock%}`

Comment: Exactly- it does print out the `<br/>`, which will be rendered in your web browser as a newline.

Comment: No, actually it is printing out the `<br/>` for me, screenshots: http://grab.by/fOTO

EDIT:the H1 was a test for the HTML tags, but it was the same with the br

Comment: Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the head of the document, and `<html>` tags surrounding it?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this as a new question, including all details of how the page is served and what browser you're using. The fact that the <h1> tags don't work indicate it's not specific to <br>.

Comment: Since this is marked as the correct answer...  @ollien is experiencing standard Jinja2 behavior.  The answer by Samarth addresses this issue.

Answer (score 54):

So it turns out that flask autoescapes html tags. So adding the `<br>` tag just renders them on screen instead of actually creating line breaks.

There are two workarounds to this:

1. **Break up the text into an array**

   ```
    text = text.split('\n')
   ```

   And then within the template, use a for loop:

   ```
    {% for para in text %}
        <p>{{para}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
   ```
2. **Disable the autoescaping**

   First we replace the `\n` with `<br>` using replace:

   ```
    text = text.replace('\n', '<br>')
   ```

   Then we disable the autoescaping by surrounding the block where we require this with

   ```
    {% autoescape false %}
        {{text}}
    {% endautoescape %}
   ```

   [However, we are discouraged from doing this:](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping)

> Whenever you do this, please be very cautious about the variables you are using in this block.

I think the first version avoids the vulnerabilities present in the second version, while still being quite easy to understand.

Comment: {% autoescape false %} ! That's what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: The link is dead. Here's the one for Flask 1.1: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping

Answer (score 17):

In case someone end up here like me, and doesn't want to use {% autoescape false %}, for safety reasons, nor braking up the text which might be inconvenient in some cases, I found a good alternative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3266740):

```
from flask import Markup
value = Markup('First line.<br>Second line.<br>')
```

and then in the jinja template:

```
{{ value }}
```

Comment: how Can I do this in django?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used Django!

Answer (score 7):

I come late to the party, but here's my solution.
HTML has a `<pre>` tag which can prove useful in this situation.

```
<pre>{{ your_text }}</pre>
```

This tag tells the browser not to automatically adjust spacing and line breaks.
To learn more about this tag check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) guide out.

Answer (score 2):

1. works for me and preserves security

I would suggest `<br>` rather than `<p>`

```
{% for para in text %}
    {{para}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

then result is less bulky

Comment: Why does using <br> preserve security but not <p>?

Comment: I think what he means by that is that it maintains security just as much as using `<p>…</p>`, but it is less bulky. [It directly addresses the answer from Samarth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41694784/2648551)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this

1. Create your template filter

```py
@app.template_filter(name='linebreaksbr')
def linebreaksbr_filter(text):
    return text.replace('\n', '<br>')
```

2. Add this to your template

```
{{ someText|linebreaksbr }}
```

This will replace every "\n" character in your text with <br>.