# new line instead of white space when using \n

Tags: flask

I'm new to Flask, so I trying to display data from my dict in HTML.

```py
next_data = '1111111\n222222'
data = {'next_data': next_data}
return render_template("data.html", data=data)
```

and this is my HTML page

```html
<div>
  <p>{{data['next_data']}}</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>{{data['name'}}</p>
</div>
```

the result I'm getting is a string with whitespace instead of `\n` but my goal is that it should display '222222' on a new line. Any tips?

```
Expected output = 111111
                  222222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41694784/5015356) answer, use `<br/>` instead of `\n`, because the string is treated as HTML, not as a Python string.

```py
next_data = '1111111\n222222'.replace('\n', '<br/>')
```

Comment: still rendered as raw, not html, need updated answer