# How to return line jumps in Python flask return?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a service that should return a string when a specific endpoint is called. But when it happens, the text is returned, but all the line jumpes '\n' are literally written instead of represent line jumps in my postman response.
Ex.:
"hello\nworld" is sent and I get "hello\nworld" instead of
"hello
world"
I've seen some solutions here on the stack overflow, but didn't understand how to implement it. Some use html scripts that seem not work on the python file. I really didn't understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244091/5853292

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244091/5853292) use `<br>` or `<br/>` instead of `\n`:

```
@app.route("/")
def test():
    return "Hello<br>World!"
```

```
Hello
World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Different from all the answers i've seen here, i found the answer to my question. Putting "
" doesn't work. What solved my problem was to add a header in my file.

```py
#code before


msg = (...) #what is to be returned  
#create the variable where you will store the returned text
response = make_response(msg, 200)
#then you add the header to  it
response.mimetype = "text/plain"
#then return
return response
```