# Flask html not rendered when using Jinja2 templating tag

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, template-engine

I'm using the (awesome) [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to build a website and I now have a problem with html not being rendered properly. I've got a line in my template with an if-else depending on whether the `public` variable is True:

```
{{ theInfo if public else '<span style="background-color: green;">this info is hidden</span>' }}
```

Unfortunately, this simply displays the html in the browser, instead of rendering it. Do I need to somehow let Jinja know that its html should be rendered?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: try without curly braces and `'`.Jinja uses `{{` for variables

Comment: @itzmeontv - The thing is that this is part of an if statement. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Jinja escapes the passed data. Therefore you need to explicitly tell Jinja that data is `safe` to use:

```
{{ theInfo if public else '<span style="background-color: green;">this info is hidden</span>' | safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display different html based on a value you need to first send this value in your call to `render_template`

python

```
def view():
   variablename = True
   return flask.render_template('page.html', public=variablename)
```

To check this value you add an if statement inside curly brackets, see code below

html

```
{% if public %}
    <p>Public is true!</p>
{% else %}
    <span ..../>
{% endif %}
```

A good first step is to go through the tutorial by Miguel Grinberg. http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world