# How to replace a string with linebreaks in Jinja2

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I have some data in jinja2 like this

```
'item1|item2|item3'
```

And I want to turn it into rendered linebreaks.  However, when I replace it with br/ tags, I get the br tags rendered on the page.  So

```
{{ 'item1|item2|item3' | replace("|", "<br/>") }}
```

renders as

```
item1<br/>item2<br/>item3<br/>
```

When I want

```
item1
item2
item3
```

on my page.  I feel like I'm missing some obvious trick here...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This has to do with autoescaping.  Solution that worked for me was:

```
{% autoescape false %}
  {{ 'item1|item2|item3' | replace("|", "<br/>") }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: but what if item1, item2, item3 needs to be escaped!?

Comment: this also works for `replace(variable, 'anyvalue')` thanks !

Comment: Technically correct, but are you sure you want to disable autoescape? Do you want to let users inject their own HTML into your template?

Comment: I updated the snippet with explicit `escape` for the original input but the official jinja2 doc [mentions how to achieve the same result with a custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#custom-filters)

Comment: I didn't want to turn off autoescape so instead I did this in Python ```new_variable = mystring.split('\n')``` and then, passing it to my Jinja template, I used a for loop: ```{% for line in new_variable %}<br />{{ line }}{% endfor %}```

Comment: Suggest to have a look at this answer, which I think offers the optimal approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65424688/4400069