# How do I stop CKEditor including HTML tags in content output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, jinja2

In my flask-app I'm using CKEditor. This is my configuration so far.

In my **layout.html** at the end of the body tag:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('editor')</script>
```

Here in my **articles.html** is the mentioned **id** for it:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ render_field(form.body, class="form-control", id="editor") }}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

This is how I am getting content back from my database when I write content using CKEditor CDN.

[image: Screenshot of editor window showing Hello World, with HTML view below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         {{ render_field(form.body, class="form-control", id="editor") | safe }}
                     </div>
                     <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></p>
                 </form>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)

Comment: Awesome, `| safe `  saves my day :) but not exact way, I just put that in the place where I rendering(fetching) my data. `<div class="list-group-item">{{ post.body | safe}}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

With Flask's setting (for security consideration), Jinja will escape all variable in the template, you need to use `safe` filter to let Jinja render it as HTML:

```
{{ post.body|safe }}
```