# "eval" statement in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, smarty, jinja2

I'm trying to convert some old Smarty templates to Jinja2.

Smarty uses an `eval` statement in the templates to render a templated string from the current context.

Is there an `eval` equivalent in Jinja2 ? Or what is a good workaround for this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [@jinja2.contextfilter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#utilities) decorator to make a [Custom Filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#custom-filters) for rendering variables:

```
from flask import render_template_string
from jinja2 import contextfilter
from markupsafe import Markup


@contextfilter
def dangerous_render(context, value):
    Markup(render_template_string(value, **context)).format()
```

Then in your template.html file:

```
{{ myvar|dangerous_render }}
```

Comment: The `render()` method on `Markup(...)` did not work for me, I think it does not have that method.

Comment: @AndreasMaier thanks, updated it to work with the latest Flask, Jinja2, and markupsafe.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers from Alan Hamlett and Hilario Nengare, I implemented the following "eval" filter for Jinja2 (>=3.0). I found that the case of undefined input should also be handled, plus I added the ability to specify additional variables as input for the expression:

```
import jinja2

@jinja2.pass_context
def filter_eval(context, input, **vars):
    if input == jinja2.Undefined:
        return input
    return jinja2.Template(input).render(context, **vars)
```

Usage, when adding filter_eval() as filter "eval":

- Template source:

  ```
  {% set rack_str = 'Rack {{ rack }}' %}
  {{ rack_str | eval(rack='A') }}
  ```
- Rendered template:

  ```
  Rack A
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar eval use case and bumped into a different stack overflow post.

This worked for me

**routes.py**

```
def index():
    html = "<b>actual eval string</b>"
    return render_template('index.html', html_str = html)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>eval jinja</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ html_str | safe }}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Reference** : [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3206344/649408)

Comment: This example does not evaluate a Jinja2 expression, which is what the OP had asked for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jinja version 3.0, contextfilter has deprecated and removed in Jinja 3.1. Use pass_context() instead. [Refer here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#custom-filters) for more details pertaining this.

```
from jinja2 import pass_context, Template
from markupsafe import Markup


@pass_context
def foo(context, value):
    return Markup(Template(value).render(context)).render()
```

then in your template

```
 {{ myvar|foo }}
```

Comment: The `render()` method on `Markup(...)` did not work for me, I think it does not have that method.