# Displaying df.head() in flask with upload button

Tags: python, flask

This question is not a duplicate of [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3206344). It deals with dataframes and is specific to a layout. Please read it carefully.

I have created a file load interface for uploading training and test data. Now I want, on the right portion of the page just opposite to the corresponding button, that `data.head()` should be printed, to get an idea of the structure of the data. This should happen after the `/upload` route is called.

I am aware of the `df.to_html()` option, but I'm not able to think where to incorporate it in the code.

Code used is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload', endpoint = 'upload_file1')

def upload_file1():
    return render_template('view.html')

@app.route('/upload', endpoint = 'upload_file3')

def upload_file3():
    return render_template('view.html')
@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'], endpoint= 'upload_file2')
def upload_file2():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      return 'file uploaded successfully'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: Why there are two renderers written for /upload? And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Because I want to create 2 buttons one for training data and one for test. Code runs fine. Now as I said, want to display the respective data.head() in front of the buttons. Just wanted some help how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass params to render_template and render using the params.

```
@app.route('/update', endpoint = 'upload_file1')
def upload_file1():
    df_table = df.head().html()
    return render_template('view.html', df_table=df_table)
```

view.html

```
{% block content %}
  {{df_table | safe}}
{% endblock %}
```