# html template to pdf with images

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am using django and trying to render invoice pdf, pdf is generating successfully but images are not in pdf.

Actually I want to add barcode image, so I dynamically generated a `.svg` file, but don't know how to put it into pdf.

Here is what I am doing ..

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

html -

```
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <span>
                {{ package_no_barcode }}
                <br>
                {{ package.package_no }}
                ....
```

view -

```
class GenerateInvoicePdf(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        package = Package.objects.get(package_no=request.GET.get('package'))
        address = package.purchase.order_product.delivery_location
        CODE128 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
        package_no_barcode = CODE128(u'{pkg_no}'.format(pkg_no=package.package_no))
        if request.user.display_username == seller.display_username:
            data = {
                 'package':package,
                 'address':address,
                 'package_no_barcode':package_no_barcode,
             }
            pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice.html', data)
            if pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %(package)
                content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
                download = request.GET.get("download")
                if download:
                    content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
                response['Content-Disposition'] = content
                return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

I also tried with cid - `<img src="cid:{{ package_no_barcode }}" alt="{{ package.package_no }}">`

**Example of svg generated**

```
CODE128 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
package_no_barcode = CODE128(u'PLAI73664PJHS')
package_no_barcode.save('PSKK')
```

generate svg -

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="23.000mm" version="1.1" width="40.000mm">
    <!--Autogenerated with python-barcode 0.9.0-->
    <g id="barcode_group">
        <rect height="100%" style="fill:white" width="100%"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="2.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="2.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="3.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="3.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="4.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="5.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="5.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="6.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="6.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="6.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="6.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="7.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="7.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="8.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="8.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="8.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="9.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="9.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="9.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="9.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="10.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="10.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="11.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="11.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="12.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="12.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="13.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="13.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="13.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="13.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="13.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="14.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.800mm" x="14.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="15.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="15.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="15.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="16.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="17.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="17.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="17.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="17.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="18.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="18.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="18.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="19.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="19.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="20.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="20.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.800mm" x="20.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="21.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="21.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="22.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="22.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="22.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="23.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="23.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="23.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="24.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="24.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="25.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="25.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="25.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="26.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="26.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="26.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="26.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="27.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="27.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="27.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="28.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="28.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="29.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="29.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="30.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="30.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="30.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="31.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="31.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="31.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="32.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="32.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="32.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="33.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="33.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="34.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="34.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="34.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="35.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="35.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="35.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="36.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="37.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="37.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="37.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="37.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <text style="fill:black;font-size:10pt;text-anchor:middle;" x="20.340mm" y="21.000mm">PLAI73664PJHS</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Update** - using `.render`, - `'package_no_barcode':package_no_barcode.render`, i can get the svg code but not for html -

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE svg\r\n PUBLIC \'-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\'\r\n
\'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\'>\r\n<svg height="23.000mm" version="1.1" width="38.000mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\r\n
<!--Autogenerated with python-barcode 0.9.0-->\r\n <g id="barcode_group">\r\n <rect height="100%" style="fill:white" width="100%"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="2.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="2.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="3.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="3.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="4.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="5.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="5.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="5.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="6.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="6.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="6.940mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="7.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="8.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="8.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="8.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="8.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="9.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="9.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="10.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="10.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="10.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="11.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="11.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="11.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="12.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="12.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="12.940mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="13.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="13.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="13.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="14.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="14.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="14.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="15.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="15.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="16.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="16.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="16.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="17.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm"
x="17.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="17.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="18.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="18.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="18.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="19.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="19.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="20.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm"
x="20.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="21.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="21.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="21.540mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="21.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="22.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="22.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="23.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="23.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="23.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="24.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="24.540mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="24.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="25.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="25.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="26.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="26.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="26.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="26.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="27.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="27.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="28.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="28.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="28.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="29.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="29.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="29.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="30.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="30.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="31.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="31.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="32.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm"
x="32.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="32.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="33.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="33.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="33.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="34.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="34.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="35.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="35.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="35.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <text
style="fill:black;font-size:10pt;text-anchor:middle;" x="19.240mm" y="21.000mm">UXXWL94HXO08</text>\r\n </g>\r\n</svg>\r\n'
```

How to make svg image with this code ?

Comment: Have you tried to put the svg code directly into the template using the `<svg>` tag and not the `<img>` tag? [more](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp). Could you add an example of the svg you are generating?

Comment: Make sure your var `package_no_barcode` is an absolute url, not relative.

Comment: actually when I put it into `<svg>` tags I am getting the text of barcode

Comment: @trinchet I don't want to save these svg files

Comment: @pazitos10 I have added the example of generated svg

Answer (score 1):

To get the svg rendered in the html, you have to get the svg text as it is (text output) and put it in your template without using the `<img>` tag.

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="23.000mm" version="1.1" width="40.000mm">
    <!--Autogenerated with python-barcode 0.9.0-->
    <g id="barcode_group">
        <rect height="100%" style="fill:white" width="100%"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="2.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="2.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="3.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="3.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="4.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="5.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="5.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="6.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="6.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="6.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="6.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="7.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="7.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="8.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="8.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="8.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="9.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="9.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="9.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="9.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="10.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="10.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="11.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="11.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="12.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="12.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="13.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="13.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="13.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="13.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="13.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="14.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.800mm" x="14.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="15.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="15.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="15.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="16.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="17.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="17.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="17.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="17.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="18.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="18.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="18.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="19.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="19.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="20.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="20.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.800mm" x="20.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="21.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="21.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="22.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="22.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="22.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="23.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="23.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="23.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="24.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="24.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="25.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="25.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="25.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="26.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="26.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="26.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="26.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="27.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="27.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="27.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="28.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="28.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="29.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="29.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="30.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="30.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="30.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="31.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="31.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="31.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="32.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="32.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="32.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="33.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="33.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="34.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="34.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="34.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="35.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="35.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="35.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="36.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="37.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="37.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="37.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="37.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>
        <text style="fill:black;font-size:10pt;text-anchor:middle;" x="20.340mm" y="21.000mm">PLAI73664PJHS</text>
    </g>
</svg>
            <span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

In the snippet you see the html already rendered but you need to find the way of getting that text and pass it to the template as a context variable, like you are doing with `package_no_barcode`.

**EDIT**

I've made a test using `jinja2` and using flask but the solution should be similar with django and its template engine.

First, make sure you get the svg code as a string in your server code. Then, pass it to the template as a context variable as I mentioned before.

In the template, you need to "evaluate" the html or in this case svg code that comes in the variable you passed before. To do that using jinja2, I used the `safe` filter.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
            {{ barcode | safe }}
            <span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

And as a result I got:

[image]

But using django's default template engine I think you need to use the [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#escape) builtin filter to get something similar.

Similar question but using flask and jinja2: [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)

Comment: please see the update, i am not getting the exact svg code for html

Comment: @PankajSharma, I edited my answer adding an example.

Comment: Thank you for answering, its working for html but in my pdf I can only see the code...I am uploading the pdf...please see that - https://www.datafilehost.com/d/c995c651