# how to convert barcode render formatted string to html

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I am generating a `.svg` file of barcode with `barcode` module.

```
CODE128 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
package_no_barcode = CODE128(u'PLAI73664PJHS')
```

when I use  - `package_no_barcode.render`, I get -

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE svg\r\n PUBLIC \'-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\'\r\n
\'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\'>\r\n<svg height="23.000mm" version="1.1" width="38.000mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\r\n
<!--Autogenerated with python-barcode 0.9.0-->\r\n <g id="barcode_group">\r\n <rect height="100%" style="fill:white" width="100%"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="2.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="2.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="3.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="3.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="4.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="5.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="5.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="5.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="6.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="6.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="6.940mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="7.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="8.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="8.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="8.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="8.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="9.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="9.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="10.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="10.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="10.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="11.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="11.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="11.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="12.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="12.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="12.940mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="13.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="13.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="13.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="14.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="14.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="14.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="15.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="15.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="16.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="16.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="16.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="17.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm"
x="17.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="17.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="18.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="18.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="18.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="19.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="19.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="20.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm"
x="20.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="21.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="21.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="21.540mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="21.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="22.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="22.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="23.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="23.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="23.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="24.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="24.540mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="24.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="25.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="25.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="26.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="26.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="26.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="26.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="27.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="27.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="28.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="28.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="28.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="29.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="29.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="29.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="30.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="30.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="31.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="31.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="32.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm"
x="32.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="32.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="33.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="33.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="33.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="34.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="34.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="35.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="35.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="35.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <text
style="fill:black;font-size:10pt;text-anchor:middle;" x="19.240mm" y="21.000mm">UXXWL94HXO08</text>\r\n </g>\r\n</svg>\r\n'
```

How to convert this string to get an html svg image ?

Answer (score 3):

the string IS the svg image. 
You can just append the string to your DOM and you will see your svg.

see: https://jsfiddle.net/o2kyqxve/1/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg\r\n PUBLIC \'-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\'\r\n
\'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\'><svg height="23.000mm" version="1.1" width="38.000mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\r\n
<!--Autogenerated with python-barcode 0.9.0-->\r\n <g id="barcode_group"> <rect height="100%" style="fill:white" width="100%"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="2.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="2.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="3.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="3.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.800mm" x="3.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="4.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="5.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="5.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="5.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="6.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="6.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="6.940mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="7.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="8.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="8.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="8.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="8.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="9.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="9.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="10.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="10.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="10.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="11.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="11.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="11.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="12.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="12.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="12.940mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="13.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="13.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="13.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="14.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="14.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="14.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="15.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="15.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="16.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.200mm" x="16.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="16.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="17.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm"
x="17.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="17.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="18.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="18.740mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="18.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="19.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="19.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="20.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm"
x="20.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="21.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="21.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="21.540mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="21.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="22.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="22.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="23.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="23.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="23.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="24.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="24.540mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="24.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="25.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="25.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="26.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="26.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="26.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="26.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="27.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="27.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="28.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="28.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.600mm" x="28.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="29.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="29.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="29.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="30.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.400mm" x="30.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.400mm" x="31.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="31.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="32.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm"
x="32.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="32.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm"
style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="33.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="33.340mm"
y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.600mm" x="33.740mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;"
width="0.600mm" x="34.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm" x="34.940mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect
height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.200mm" x="35.140mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:white;" width="0.200mm"
x="35.340mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <rect height="15.000mm" style="fill:black;" width="0.400mm" x="35.540mm" y="1.000mm"/>\r\n <text
style="fill:black;font-size:10pt;text-anchor:middle;" x="19.240mm" y="21.000mm">UXXWL94HXO08</text> </g></svg>
```

Comment: That's fine.. but when I covert It into pdf, it only shows the code, not svg file ...see this - https://www.datafilehost.com/d/c995c651 , I think the `/r/n` is making problem

Comment: How do you convert it to a pdf?

Comment: please see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260907/html-template-to-pdf-with-images/