# Dynamically conditionally formatting text - if word in list

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a flask app that returns a template with dynamically generated text. I want to bold specific words in the text variable based on a list variable that is also dynamically generated.

Lets say my two variables are as below

```
text = "Stephen went to the park on Tuesday with Sarah.
        Stephen couldn't go to my birthday party."

list=['Stephen', 'Sarah', 'Tuesday']
```

desired html output:
**Stephen** went to the park on **Tuesday** with **Sarah**. **Stephen** couldn't go to my birthday party.

Im stumped with how to approach a problem like this, any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Edit:
Python code

```
return render_template('results.html', ctext=boldened_text)
```

Html code

```
<h6>Your Text was</h6>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><p>{{ctext}}</p></div>
```

Comment: So you want to *replace* "Stephen" with "<b>Stephen </b>" in a *string*?

Comment: Yes, any instances of words in my list variable will need bold formatting in HTML text output

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2) post for how to render the html. `Markup` looks best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finer control, I'd advise using a for loop (simplified as a list comprehension in this example):

```
text = "Stephen went to the park on Tuesday with Sarah. Stephen couldn't go to my birthday party."

filter_list = ['Stephen', 'Sarah', 'Tuesday']

boldened = " ".join(["<b>{}</b>".format(word) if word.strip() in filter_list else word for word in text.split(" ")])
```

To see what this outputs use:

```
print(boldened)
```

Expected output:

```
"<b>Stephen</b> went to the park on <b>Tuesday</b> with Sarah. <b>Stephen</b> couldn't go to my birthday party."
```

**NOTE:** remember that in Python `list` is a type, don't use it as an identifier for variables.

Also, you're getting the `<b>` tags printed as plain text because you're not rendering your `ctext` variable as HTML, write this instead:

```
{{ ctext | safe }}
```

**WARNING:** only use `safe` with strings that you're absolutely sure are ***actually safe***!

Good luck.

Comment: It looks like your code is working for the most part, however my html page displays the <b> tags alongside the text without formatting into bold ex: <b>Stephen</b>. Ill add my html side code to my original post.

Comment: @BadKarma1122 I've updated my answer, accept if it works, let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Loop over all words
for word in list:
  # replace the word by bold tags with the word in between
  text = text.replace(word, '<b>%s</b>' % word)
```

Comment: not necessarily searching for names, but any words in the list e.x. Tuesday

Comment: `name` is just a variable, you could use `word` instead

Comment: Edit: Ahh, you got me. I havn't been reading till the 3. element of the list;-)