# How to convert Python string code to HTML for Flask Jinja templating?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to modularize my `index.html` file by having separate python files. Is there a way to convert say a Python string to HTML code? I know Flask uses Jinja templating and I've used it to extensively, but the kind of work I'm trying to do is as follows:

This is my HTML Code:

```
<article id="portfolios_RemoteSensing">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"> Machine Learning and Remote Sensing</h2>
        <hr>
    <div style="text-align:left;">

    </div>
</article>
```

I want to encapsulate this as a python string then I'll jsut reference it through Jinja

```
x = "HTML CODE ABOVE"

{{ x }}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pass `x` to your template and use `{{ x|safe }}`.

Also see [this for some alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2).