# Is it possible to style a part of a label in Flask-WTForms?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I generate a form via Flask-WTF.

The relevant checkbox looks like this:

```
    conditions = BooleanField(
        "I agree to the above conditions.", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

I'd like to have the `I agree` bold or strong - **NOT** the rest of the sentence.

I cannot pass in HTML tags, as they get escaped and rendered as text.

This would look like this:

```
[] <strong>I agree</strong> to the above conditions.
```

I'd like to get this result:

**I agree** to the above conditions.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the other answer by @gaefan, I read more about Jinja templating and the `safe` filter and came up with a another working solution.

```
from flask import Markup

label_for_conditions = Markup('<span class="customClass">I agree</span> to the above conditions.')
conditions = BooleanField(label_for_conditions, validators=[DataRequired()])
```

This solution does not need even a `safe` filter in the template.

This answer is inspired by the following discussion:

[Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)

It is not a perfect solution, as now HTML and Python is mixed in the form definition, but it looks like you have to make a compromise.

Comment: For [Flask 3.0](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/changes/#version-3-0-0) and up, you will have to use `from markupsafe import Markup` ( also see [GitHub issue/pull request #5223](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/5223) )

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to just do it in the template. Instead of:

```
{{ user_form.conditions.errors }}{{ user_form.conditions.label_tag }}<br />{{ user_form.conditions }}
```

do:

```
{{ user_form.conditions.errors }}<strong>I agree</strong> to the above conditions.<br />{{ user_form.conditions }}
```

I haven't tested this, but you may be able to do:

```
conditions = BooleanField(
    "<strong>I agree</strong> to the above conditions.", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

and then, in the template:

```
{{ user_form.conditions.errors }}{{ user_form.conditions.label_tag|safe }}<br />{{ user_form.conditions }}
```

Comment: While your second answer still escapes the html tags, and thus prints them as text, your first answer is as simple as brilliant. Your second answer was not in vain. I read more about `safe` and Jinja templating and came up with another working answer, which I will post in a minute. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

- When creating the Field using **render_kw**.
- When rendering the Field in the template (when the field is being called [`form.field()`]).

---

### Initialize Field with style:

All the [Field objects](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/) in WTForms have a **render_kw** arg in `__init__`.

> render_kw (dict) – If provided, a dictionary which provides default keywords that will be given to the widget at render time.

When your template is being rendered, Jinja2 is going to read this **render_kw**.
In your case, you can define:

```
conditions = BooleanField(
    "I agree to the above conditions.", validators=[DataRequired()],
    render_kw={"style": "font-weight: bold;")
```

### Rendering while templating

When Jinja2 is rendering, you can specify other rendering options by **calling the field**.

```
form.field()
```

> `__call__(**kwargs)`: Render this field as HTML, using keyword args as additional attributes.
>
> [...]
>
> In all of the WTForms HTML widgets, keyword arguments are turned to
> HTML attributes, though in theory a widget is free to do anything it
> wants with the supplied keyword arguments, and widgets don’t have to
> even do anything related to HTML.

So in your template file, you can do something like that:

```
{{ form.field(style="font-weight: bold;") }}
```

*Note that there is an exception for the class keyword, probably reserved by something else, then the key should be `class_`.*

---

[Source: Fields - WTForms Documencation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer, even with an alternate proposal. Unfortunately, this does not answer my question. I am super sorry that I have not made my question more explicit - I only need to style a part of the label - not the complete label. Both your solutions apply only to the complete label.

Comment: Exactly, I did not notice that you wanted only a part of the label. Nevermind, my answer will probably be useful for you later.

Comment: While I knew about adding attributes within the template, I did not know that you can already initialize a field with `render_kw`! So, I learned something new! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WTForm 2.3.3 on Flask 1.1.2 and I ended up using the following since piping the label itself, the label_tag, etc. to `safe` were not working for me but this does:

```
{{ field.label.text|safe }}
```