# Embed Python Output That is HTML in HTML Page

Tags: python, html

Is there a way I can embed this code in the HTML file rather than have it be text? I'm sorry if that is an awful explanation, but the code and the picture should better put into context my thinking.

Python:

```
table = [best_words[0:5]]
p = (tabulate(table, tablefmt='html'))
end = time.time()
final_time = '{:.2f}'.format((end-start))
return render_template('index.html', prediction=('{}'.format(p)), final_time=final_time)
```

Output of Python:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>the</td><td>a</td><td>,</td><td>-</td><td>that</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

HTML File:

```
<h5>Genrated text:</h5>
</div>
<table> <tbody>{{ prediction }} </tbody> </table></div></div> </header>
```

[image]

Comment: It would help if you tagged what framework you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28489615/9243482)

```
<table> <tbody>{{ prediction|safe }} </tbody> </table></div></div> </header>
```

Should do it i think

Answer (score 0):

use code tag

```
<code>
-- Something here
</code>
```