# Handling &#39; in JS

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have a simple code populating a list of string data from python/flask to the template.
In the rendered html, strings are within `&#39;` instead of apostrophes or double quotes. It is not a problem for the plain text, but JS cannot decode it. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

**app.py**

```
def index():
  data = ['2021-01-13 05:35:01', '2021-01-13 05:40:02', '2021-01-13 05:45:01', '2021-01-13 05:50:02']
  return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

**index.html - code**

```
<body>
  {{ data }}
</body>

<script>
  var x = {{ data }};
</script>
```

**index.html - rendered html**

```
<body>
[&#39;2021-01-13 05:35:01&#39;, &#39;2021-01-13 05:40:02&#39;, &#39;2021-01-13 05:45:01&#39;, &#39;2021-01-13 05:50:02&#39;]
</body>

<script>
  var x = [&#39;2021-01-13 05:35:01&#39;, &#39;2021-01-13 05:40:02&#39;, &#39;2021-01-13 05:45:01&#39;, &#39;2021-01-13 05:50:02&#39;];
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't HTML escape the characters you want to execute as JS code. That's not really a JS problem - needs to be handled on the backend side.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2