# json.dumps return invalid json in flask view

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple code:

```
products_list: list = [{"product_name": "product #1"}, {"product_name": "product #2"}]
return render_template('index.html', data=json.dumps(products_list))
```

My index template:

```
<body>
    <script>
        console.log({{ data }});
    </script>
</body>
```

But on the page i get an
[invalid json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2peTm.png) with &#34, #1&#34 characters.

```
 console.log([{&#34;product_name&#34;: &#34;product #1&#34;}, {&#34;product_name&#34;: &#34;product #2&#34;}]);
```

Why it happens?

Comment: Why are you using a template for code? Code is already code; can’t you just pass the object as a function parameter or something?  The template rendering engine assumes templates are HTML, which is why it’s turning the quotation marks in your JSON into HTML entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that flask is escaping the quotes in your JSON by replacing them with `&#34;`. You can disable this by adding the `|safe` filter to your template.

So your HTML will be:

```
<body>
    <script>
        console.log({{ data|safe }});
    </script>
</body>
```

---

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)