# How to pass html code to a render_template in flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to pass a variable to a render_template as html code, but Flask automatically changes the strings instead of returning the plaintext. For instance, if I were to try to say:

```py
@app.route("/")
def index():
 return render_template("index.html", code = "<p>Hello</p>")
```

Flask passes the variable "code" to the website as:

> <p> Hello </p>

So it renders out to just be

> Hello

instead of recognizing the HTML tags. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2/3266740#3266740)

Comment: what are the contents of index.html?

Comment: Update: @PGHE linked me to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2/3266740#3266740). This question is resolved