# pass newline into jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

If I have in my jinja2 template

```
<td>{{ cell.text }}</td>
```

where in my python code I have

```
cell['text'] = 'Some Text\nSome Other Text'
```

I get

```
Some Text Some Other Text
```

When I was expecting

```
Some Text
Some Other Text
```

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Did you place it in {{}}?

Comment: Try using <br> or <pre> instead of \n ?

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea At the top I show `<td>{{ cell.text }}</td>`, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @ValF. I tried that!  The result was "Some Text<br>Some Other Text", it didn't seem to parse it as HTML.  I also tried "U+000A" and something like "&0016;", I forget what because I deleted it and can't find the code again for some reason.  In both cases it just passed the literal string in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)