# How to customize Validation Error message in Flask-WTF

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a custom validator in a [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/) `form` that looks like this:

```py
def is_some_condition_true(arg: str) -> bool:
    return arg == "example"

def validation_func(self, arg: str) -> None:
    if not is_some_condition_true(arg):
        raise ValidationError("The <strong>validation</strong> failed")
```

As you can see, I'm trying to insert html in the error message. Unfortunately, the result looks like this:

[image]

**How can I put html in the validation error message without it being escaped?**

Comment: Provided you use Jinja templating, it is simple to do this using Jinja's [safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3206344/15368978) filter. Wherever you display your error message, simply add `|safe`, as explained in the linked post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3266740/4713169) from the question kindly pointed out by [@Patrick Yoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15368978/patrick-yoder), as I couldn't quite get the `|safe` trick to work and it just feels a bit tidier this way.

This is how my code looks like now:

```
from markupsafe import Markup

def is_some_condition_true(arg: str) -> bool:
    return arg == "example"

def validation_func(self, arg: str) -> None:
    if not is_some_condition_true(arg):
        error_msg = Markup("The <strong>validation</strong> failed")
        raise ValidationError(error_msg)
```