# Flask , rendering template with additional HTML tags

Tags: python, flask

I have a route:

```
@app.route("/ticket/<int:ticket_id>")
def ticket(ticket_id):
    update_list = get_data(ticket_id)
    return render_template('ticket.html', ticket_id=ticket_id, update_list=update_list)
```

Now update_list contains list of notes with HTML tags included, for example:

update_list[0]

```
<p> This is my first note </p>
```

ticket.html:

```
<h1> {{ update_list[0] }} </h1>
```

If I try go into http://localhost/ticket/12345 I can see page renders with additional
HTML tags(h1 tag is rendered properly):

```
<p> This is my first note </p>
```

Is there a way to make Flask render these additional HTML "<p>" (or any other) tags ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)

Comment: Are you trying to loop through `update_list` to render each result? Can you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: Yes, I'm looping through contents of update_list:


`{% for item in update_list %}`

Comment: @PatrickYoder adding |safe worked like a charm, awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Adding safe fixed the issue:

```
<h1> {{ update_list[0]|safe }} </h1>
```