# python dict to json and sending to HTML using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I need to print a big python dictionary in HTML with neat format to read using Flask.

Lets take this `dict` as example:

```
a={'a':True, 'b':False}
a_json=json.dumps(a) # {"a": true, "b": false}
return render_template("index.html", a_json=a_json)
```

In HTML:

```
  <div class="w3-container">
      <pre id="dict"></pre>
  </div>

  <script>
    var data = {{a_json}}
    document.getElementById("dict").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
  </script>
```

This does not showing the data, when I checked the open the "view page source", I see that the JSON data is different, and there are extra characters are available like this:

[image]

When, I give the JSON data directly in the `script` tag, I got the dictionary visible in the web page.

How to make this JSON data visible in the web page (or)
How to make the `dict` visible in html in neat format?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put the JSON string directly to the HTML part of the page? There is no need for Javascript at all.

Comment: @VPIB, to show the json data in neat way, I am using the javascript, Do you know any possible way to print the python dict as it is in html with neat way of visualisation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```js
var data = {{a_json}}
```

to

```js
var data = {{ a_json | safe }}
```

See [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)