# flask app: Flask application is displaying the HTML file, not rendering it as a web page

Tags: html, flask, webdeploy

I have a trained machine learning model that I want to use in a Flask web application. When I run my Python code (app.py), the Flask application displays the HTML file as plain text instead of rendering it as a web page. Below is my Python code (app.py) and my HTML code (index.html). I'm new to web development, and I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,url_for
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

#Load your trained CNN model
model = load_model(os.path.join('models', 'BreastCancerDetection.h5'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    # Get the uploaded image from the request
    uploaded_file = request.files['BreastUltrasoundImage']

    # Process the uploaded image
    img = image.load_img(uploaded_file, target_size=(256, 256))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array / 255, axis=0)

    # Make predictions
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)



    class_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

    return render_template('index.html', predictions=class_labels[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Breast Cancer Detector</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Breast Cancer Prediction</h1>
    <div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('predict') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="BreastUltrasoundImage" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" required>
            <button type="submit">Predict</button>
        </form>
        <h4 style="color: violet;">{{ predictions }}</h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked my directory as below.

```
project_folder/
├── app.py
├── templates/
│    └── index.html
└── models/
    └── BreastCancerDetection.h5
```

Lilly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, it didn't work, my web looks like the html file itself'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Breast Cancer Detector</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Breast Cancer Prediction</h1>
    <div>
        <form action="/predict" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="BreastUltrasoundImage" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" required>
            <button type="submit">Predict</button>
        </form>
        <h4 style="color: violet;"></h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>'

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved. I switched from TextEdit to Atom to write my html code, second change is the python code for uploading the images:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    uploaded_file = request.files['BreastUltrasoundImage']
    if uploaded_file:
        file_contents = uploaded_file.read()
        return file_contents
```

Thanks,